# what causes airborne bodies to tilt?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, lift

Imagine a Helium-inflated oblate spheroid floating still **(A)**.
Buoyancy force cancels gravity force on Y axis. Object is tied to ground with a rope.

If a wind force is applied on X axis, why does the spheroid tilt , thus inducing an aerodynamic lift & drag **(C)**, instead of simply keeping non-tilted position with aerodynamic drag only **(B)**?

[image]

Comment: The tension force of the rope will create a moment that tilts the balloon.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If that was a solid body (pendulum-like) - of course. Here, however, is a flexible system and to me it seems more mass-center related (?).

Comment: Well the balloon itself is a solid body. The gas inside will not all tilt rigidly, different parts of it will rotate different angles at different speeds,so its motion will be more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the ballon to stand upright in calm air. Now add a light breeze. Aerodynamic drag will push the ballon sideways. The drag force will act along a line parallel to the wind direction which runs through the center of the ballon and is above the point at which the tether is connected. This force will create a pitching moment and pitch the balloon up.

If you use a toroidal shape (a donut-shaped ballon, in other words) and manage to tether it right at the center, this pitching moment will be zero. Still, any imbalance in moments will make it pitch up or down, and then the lift forces which come with a nonzero angle of attack will dominate the picture.

The center of pressure is where all pressure forces acting on the sphere can be summed up. All bodies have their center of pressure somewhere between the forward edge (when slender and long along the direction of flow) and 25% (when wide and short) of their streamwise length, and your ellipsoid is no exception. This creates a pitching moment because the lift forces will always act quite a bit ahead of the center.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I suppose I should have started approaching this problem with a simpler form (such as inflated sphere).